# Apollo client fetchMore from useQuery fires two network requests

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to implement a `loadMore` feature that appends items to the original list using `useQuery`'s `fetchMore` function.

```js
const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_PODCAST_SERIES, {
    variables: {
      limit: 12,
      offset: 0,
      pathOrId: `${site}/podcast/${slug}`,
    },
    nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });

const length = data.PodcastSeriesQuery.podcastSeries.podcastEpisodes.length;

return <..>
  ...
   <button onClick={() => {
       fetchMore({
         variables: { offset: length } 
       })
    }}>load more</button>
</..>
```

the query looks like this

```
const GET_PODCAST_SERIES = gql`
  query PodcastSeries($pathOrId: String, $limit: Int, $offset: Int) {
    PodcastSeriesQuery(pathOrId: $pathOrId) {
      podcastSeries(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
        id
        ...
        podcastEpisodes {
          id
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

the cache looks like this

```js
cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            PodcastSeriesQuery: {
              keyArgs: ['pathOrId'],
              merge(_, incoming) {
                return incoming;
              },
            },
          },
        },
        PodcastSeries: {
          fields: {
            podcastEpisodes: {
              merge(existing = [], incoming) {
                return [...existing, ...incoming];
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }),
```

The issue is that whenever I call `fetchMore`, it sends two network requests with the default one always fired. For example

click load more the first time

```
 - network request 1 -> offset: 12, limit: 12, pathOrId: ...

 - network request 2 -> offset: 0, limit: 12, pathOrId: ...
```

click load more the second time

```
  - network request 1 -> offset: 36 (even thought it should be 24, but it is still correct because the first click fetches twice making the data.list bigger), limit: 12, pathOrId: ...

  - network request 2 -> offset: 0, limit: 12, ....
```

So the default query is always fired..

How should I fix this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just simply because the cache isn't right. I solved it by doing this

```js
cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            PodcastSeriesQuery: {
              keyArgs: ['pathOrId'],
              merge(existing, incoming) {
                // before -> return incoming || existing;
                return existing || incoming; // after
              },
            },
          },
        },
        PodcastSeries: {
          fields: {
            podcastEpisodes: {
              merge(existing = [], incoming) {
                return [...existing, ...incoming];
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }),
```